# Debugging incosistent LUKS/cryptsetup behaviour

Tags: linux, fedora, luks, cryptsetup

I've encountered this issue a few times but so far I've been unable to reliably reproduce this/find the root cause.
Where do I go from here? It seems like taking `hexdump` of the header might help, so maybe keep taking snapshots of `hexdump` of the first key slot area until it does this again?

Symptom:

- After a reboot/shutdown, *sometimes* the passphrase for the first key slot is rejected with `No key available for this passphrase.`
- *Sometimes* Header backup does not seem to help. Running something like `cryptsetup -v --header backupheader.bin open /dev/device test` still returns `No key...` for the first slot. But one out of five times recovery from header backup works (again this sometimes works, sometimes does not). `cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore` produces the same result.

Observations:

- The partition itself seems to be fine. `lsblk` and `cryptsetup isLuks` shows nothing abnormal.
- `cryptsetup luksDump` always works and shows the first slot is enabled.
- I've since added a few more keys and these keys always work. It's the first key slot that seems to have issues.
- If I unlock the partition using the second or any other key but the first one, the first key slot usually works on the next boot.

Env:

- X1 Carbon Gen 6, Fedora 28

Comment: If the key in the first key slot isn't working reliably, you might want to remove it and recreate it. If the new key is also unstable, the slot may be damaged, which means the drive likely has an error in that area.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try that when the problem comes back. I've only had this laptop for a week so while unlikely if it's really due to drive damage I'd send it back under warranty.